# Manual action not working on selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I 've made a Python script to scrape data from the site using selenium Chrome driver.

There are javascript actions for selecting odds type and it has been working well for a month.

[selecting odd format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2CrP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6k8h.png)

The site url is  https://oddsportal.com

```
    chrome_options = Options()
    #chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-logging']);
    chrome_options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
    
    chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
    
    driverpath = "C:\driver_exe\chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
      .....
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(driverpath,options=chrome_options)
    driver1.get(turl)
    driver1.execute_script("changeOddsFormat(1);")  // for selecting EU odds
```

The script code has been working well but from yesterday it's not working .

I've thought Javascript is suddenly blocked on selenium and tried to select it by clicking manually.

But manual clicking is also not working now.

Maybe some extra options were added in oddsportal.com and I need to set another option or something?

Please check them and help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false`.

Comment: I've tried it , but it's still not working.

Comment: maybe they change JavaScript code and maybe they made mistake in code and it doesn't work any more. If they broke code then you can't fix it. You can only check if the same problem is with different browsers (Chrome/Firefox/Edge) and without adblockers - and if there is still problem then you could send message to admins of this page that they have broken code.